# create archive of google docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running the following code. It says

> unexpected error in **UrlFetchApp.fetch()**

```
function archive(){
 var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("docs");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://docs.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerkey);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

    var requestData = {

    "method": "POST",
    "headers": { "GData-Version": "3.0" },
    "oAuthServiceName": "docs",
       "payload":getPayload(),
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };

 var url='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/archive'
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);

  }
function getPayload() {

var xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
  '<atom:entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007">'+
  '<docs:archiveConversion source="application/vnd.google-apps.document" target="application/msword"/>'+
  '<docs:archiveConversion source="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" target="text/csv"/>'+
  '<docs:archiveConversion source="application/pdf" target="application/pdf"/>'+
  </atom:entry>';
   Logger.log(xml)
   return xml;
  }


If you have another way to do this, please let me know asap.

Thank you in advance!!
```

Comment: Did you try running it from the Editor itself by hitting the "Play" button? Are you seeing an authorization dialog first?

Comment: ya, i tried it from the editor....and i got authorization dialog

Answer (score 0):

I can share a current experience I am having with UrlFetchApp.fetch()

Prior to today, my script (in several sheets) was working fine, but today it gives an error.  After some tinkering I have got things running again by changing https to http in the url.

This may well be coincidental to your problem, I don't claim to know, but I am posting in case it helps.

(*in my case, the error reported as:*

> [Unexpected error: https://theURLcalled...(line44)]

*where line 44 is the code*
    `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Following examples might be helpful to you. These examples use Google OAuth and UrlFetch

https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth/get-the-document-list-of-a-domain-user
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth/share-docs-between-domain-users
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/applications/doodle-for-your-domain